# Displaying image on jframe

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class test extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocation(400, 100);
        frame.setTitle("hello world");

        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon();
        img.getClass().getResource("/testing/youlost.png");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel(img);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

I run these codes in eclipse and the frame did pop up because of `frame.pack()` and did not give any errors but the image did not appear. could someone help me with the code?

Comment: You are missing `frame.add(panel)` before `frame.pack()`.

Comment: it did not work

Comment: I think you are missing also a `setVisible` on the JLabel. I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is that you are not setting the image for your `ImageIcon`.

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(test.class.getResource("image.png"));
```

And don't forget to add the `JPanel` into the `JFrame`.

```
frame.add(panel);
```

---

Full code would be,

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setLocation(400, 100);
frame.setTitle("hello world");

ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(test.class.getResource("image.png"));
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel label = new JLabel(img);
panel.add(label);
panel.setVisible(true);

frame.add(panel);
frame.pack();
```

[image]

Comment: @xxboomxx Try it now. I've tested it. Working perfectly, unless your image path is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you call

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

right after creating the object. Try calling it after

```
frame.pack();
```

In addition to that, you need to add the panel to the frame using

```
frame.add(panel);
```

Comment: No I have not but my mistake was I did not set my image to the imageicon